# iTunes is changing the number/order of tracks in an album when it loads into my iPod. I want the tracks to stay in order

Tags: itunes

iTunes changes the number (and therefore) the order of tracks in an album when make a new playlist. Therefore, I cannot listen to an album in the correct order. I want the tracks to stay in order when I create a new playlist. It is worse than shuffle because the actual number of the tracks gets changed, so I cannot tell what order the tracks should be in.

Comment: When you say it changes the "number", do you mean the actual track number, or the number all the way to left of the track when viewing the playlist (as shown in [this screenshot](http://i.stack.imgur.com/YvU4z.png))?

Comment: Are you certain all the tracks on the album are "checked" so they are all *supposed* to be synced?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why this is happening, but you can fix it by clicking on a track, going to File > Get Info (or <kbd>⌘ Cmd</kbd>-<kbd>I</kbd>) and changing the track numbers back to the correct information.

To get the correct track number, you can try googling the album. Somewhere will surely have the titles and track numbers.

Comment: ah, there it is "kbd", not "key" :D

Answer (score 0):

Easy to EDIT playlist and put in order downloaded or whatever.  Click DONE and will put in new order.  My problem is I have to do this every time I open iTunes.  I agree it won't "stay" in the order set.  Especially a problem for downloaded books.  Need to make sure each playlist is in correct order before you sync.

Answer (score 0):

There is no answer.  The latest version of iTunes completely boned all users  You cannot drag folders into a playlist and have the order of the songs be proper.  Yes you can edit them by switching to "songs" view and sorting by "playlist order" (the first column), but that is a major hassle and I now hate iTunes because of it.

The only way I have found to import a folder of songs and have them retain their proper order, is instead of dragging in the folder, highlighting and dragging the songs.  For each folder.  It's a terrible waste of time but at least you don't have to rearrange each song in the playlist.

It started with version 12 and there is absolutely NO GOOD reason for this, and they'd better fix it soon.

Answer (score 0):

I may have found an answer, go to view In iTunes and select "sort by playlist order", it seems to have stopped tracks on a CD  appearing in the wrong order.
Hope this helps.